# WPF listView Обновление эллементов

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, binding

Всем привет. У меня есть listView. При открытии окна я помещаю в него данные:

```
listView.ItemsSource = _modelAuthor.Items;
```

`_modelAuthor.Items` изменяется внутри программы, и при изменении посылает событие в это окно.

Как обновить содержимое `listView` ?

Попытался так, но ничего не обновляет, а при изменении размера окна выскакивает ошибка :

> Объект ItemsControl не соответствует своему источнику элементов.

```
private void ModelAuthorUpdated(object sender, ModelEventArgs<Author> e)
    {
        listView.ItemsSource = _modelAuthor.Items;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Исправил с помощью метода `Refresh`

```
 private void ModelAuthorUpdated(object sender, ModelEventArgs<Author> e)
    {
        listView.Items.Refresh();
    }
```